# The system cannot find the file specified using X509Certificate2 to connect Google OAuth2.0 in an Azure Server

Tags: c#, azure, x509certificate2

I'm using this code to connect to Google OAuth2.0 and I'm using the C# libraries.

```
using (var tImpersonationContext = new ImpersonationContext(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImpersonationDomain"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImpersonationUser"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImpersonationPassword"]))
{
    string[] tScopes = new string[] { AnalyticsService.Scope.Analytics };
    var tKeyFilePath = Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]), String.Format("GoogleCertificates\\{0}", this.OAuthKeyName));
    var tServiceAccountEmail = this.OAuthServiceAccountEmail;

    //loading the Key file
    var tCertificate = new X509Certificate2(tKeyFilePath, this.OAuthKeyPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
    var tCredential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(tServiceAccountEmail)
    {
        Scopes = tScopes
    }.FromCertificate(tCertificate));

    if (tCredential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result)
    {
        this.SessionToken = tCredential.Token.AccessToken;
    }
}
```

In my dev enviroment everything works just perfect but when I move the app to my Azure Server I got this error:

> The system cannot find the file specified.

When I try to execute this line:

```
var tCertificate = new X509Certificate2(tKeyFilePath, this.OAuthKeyPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

I'm sure that the path is correct, in fact if I copy and paste the path in the File Explorer the wizard to import the certificate starts.

I'm sure that the impersonation is working because the line is excecuted.

I have tried to change it to:

```
var tCertificate = new X509Certificate2(tKeyFilePath, this.OAuthKeyPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
```

Or this:

```
var tCertificate = new X509Certificate2(tKeyFilePath, this.OAuthKeyPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.UserProtected | X509KeyStorageFlags.DefaultKeySet);
```

And nothing is working, in fact everything I have tried from other questions of this web site are not working.

If it help is a Windows App that I pretend to use in a task scheduled, to get data from Google Analytics.

Does someone have any idea why is not working in the Azure Server??

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I have tried to install the certificate and I have change the code to this:

```
var tCertificate = new X509Certificate2(tKeyFilePath, this.OAuthKeyPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
```

But now I get this error:

> Key not valid for use in specified state.

Comment: I believe the recommended way to store certificates on Azure is this way: https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/27/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have change all the code an the aproach and now is working.

First you have to instal your certificate in the MMC manager inside trusted root certificates authorities under certificates and it have to be set as a local machine.

And then you just have to use this code:

```
X509Store tCertStore = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
tCertStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509Certificate2Collection tCertCollection = tCertStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, this.OAuthKeyFingerprint, false);

// Get the first cert with the thumbprint
if (tCertCollection.Count > 0)
{
    // header
    var tHeader = new { typ = "JWT", alg = "RS256" };

    // claimset
    var tTimes = GetExpiryAndIssueDate();
    var tClaimset = new
    {
        iss = this.OAuthServiceAccountEmail,
        scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics",
        aud = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token",
        iat = tTimes[0],
        exp = tTimes[1],
    };

    JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    // encoded header
    var tHeaderSerialized = ser.Serialize(tHeader);
    var tHeaderBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tHeaderSerialized);
    var tHeaderEncoded = Convert.ToBase64String(tHeaderBytes);

    // encoded claimset
    var tClaimsetSerialized = ser.Serialize(tClaimset);
    var tClaimsetBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tClaimsetSerialized);
    var tClaimsetEncoded = Convert.ToBase64String(tClaimsetBytes);

    // input
    var tInput = tHeaderEncoded + "." + tClaimsetEncoded;
    var tInputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tInput);

    X509Certificate2 tCertificate = tCertCollection[0];

    // signiture
    var tRSA = tCertificate.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;

    var tCspParam = new CspParameters
    {
        KeyContainerName = tRSA.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName,
        KeyNumber = tRSA.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyNumber == KeyNumber.Exchange ? 1 : 2,
        Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore
    };
    var tAesCsp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024, tCspParam) { PersistKeyInCsp = true };
    var tSignatureBytes = tAesCsp.SignData(tInputBytes, "SHA256");
    var tSignatureEncoded = Convert.ToBase64String(tSignatureBytes);

    // jwt
    var tJWT = tHeaderEncoded + "." + tClaimsetEncoded + "." + tSignatureEncoded;

    HttpClient tClient = new HttpClient();

    Dictionary<string, string> tPost = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"assertion", tJWT},
            {"grant_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer"}
        };

    FormUrlEncodedContent tContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(tPost);

    var tURI = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token";

    HttpResponseMessage tResult = tClient.PostAsync(tURI, tContent).Result;
    TokenResponse tTokenObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenResponse>(tResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

    this.SessionToken = tTokenObject.access_token;
}

tCertStore.Close();
```

I hope this help someone.

Happy coding.